# How should I set up my includes layout for my program?

Tags: c++, header-files

I'm currently trying to make a RPG game and I'm running into some trouble. This is the layout I have so far.

Classes:

- Actor - Base class for anything that 'exists' such as units, projectiles, etc.
- Unit - Inherits Actor, basis for all units.
- Game - It will only have a single instance, and it'll contains pointers to all objects in the game. I plan to make it call a virtual function gameTick on all actors every 0.1 seconds.

The problem I'm having is that I'd like all Actors to have a pointer to the Game instance. If I wanted to have a spell that does 500 radius area damage, I'd like Game to find and return all Unit pointers within that range.

My problem is if I include Game in Actor's header file my program won't compile. How can I have my actors have access to Game? Or am I going about this the wrong way?

Thanks in advance.

```
// START main.cpp

#include <iostream>
#include "game.h"

int main()
{
    std::cout << "All done\n";

    return 0;
}

// END main.cpp



// START actor.h

#ifndef __ACTOR_H_
#define __ACTOR_H_

#include <iostream>

//#include "game.h" Causes many errors if uncommented

class Actor
{
public:
    Actor();

    std::string name_;
};

#endif

// END    actor.h



// START actor.cpp

#include "actor.h"

Actor::Actor()
{
    name_ = "Actor class";
}
// END actor.cpp



// START unit.h

#ifndef __UNIT_H_
#define __UNIT_H_

#include "actor.h"

class Unit : public Actor
{
public:
    Unit();
};

#endif

// END unit.h



// START unit.cpp

#include "unit.h"

Unit::Unit()
{
    name_ = "Unit class";
}

// END unit.cpp



// START game.h

#ifndef __GAME_H_
#define __GAME_H_

#include <vector>

#include "unit.h"

class Game
{
public:
    std::vector< Actor * > actors_;
    std::vector< Unit * > units_;
};

#endif

// END game.h
```

Comment: What about thinking about breaking some things out into interfaces to fix dependency issues? I assume the errors you were getting had to do with circular dependencies.

Comment: unit.h includes actor.h, actor.h includes game.h, game.h includes unit.h/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of doing:

```
#include "actor.h"
#include "unit.h"
```

you can simply forward declare the two classes:

```
class Actor;
class Unit;
```

Since you're only using pointers, the compiler just needs to know that the type is a class, it doesn't need to know anything else.  Now in the cpp file, you'd need to do the `#include`s

Answer (score 1):

A forward declaration might be enough for your purposes. The only situations when a fwd declaration is not enough are

- if you have to instantiate an object of the class: the compiler needs to know how that object has to be constructed
- if you need to access public methods/attributes of that class: the compiler needs to know how those methods work or what type of attribute you are trying to access.

If you are not doing either of the above, than a forward declaration is enough.